# Cartesian Product

Tags: c#, cartesian-product

I am currently writing a program dealing with Cartesian Product.  I have figured out the first part of inputting two numbers and getting the set for each number inputted.  But what i need is the final product of both numbers.
In other words I am looking for my product to look something like this:

```
{ (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), ... }
```

Here is my code for right now with the last part of where I need help.

```
private void btnCal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iN, iM, i, j;
    string strOut1, strOut2, strOut;
    bool bN, bM;

    bN = int.TryParse(txtN.Text, out iN);
    bM = int.TryParse(txtM.Text, out iM);

    if (bN && bM && iM > 0 && iM > 0)
    {
        strOut1 = "{1";

        for (i = 2; i <= iM; i++)
            strOut1 += "," + i;
        txtFirst.Text = strOut1 + "}";

        strOut2 = "{1";

        for (j = 2; j <= iN; j++)
            strOut2 += "," + j;
        txtSecond.Text = strOut2 + "}";
    }

    //HERE IS WHERE THE PRODUCT CODE WILL BE AT

    if (bN && bM && iM > 0 && iM > 0)
    {
        for (i = 2; i <= iM; i++)
            for (j = 2; j <= iN; j++)

        strOut = ("strOut1");

        txtProduct.Text = strOut + " }";
    }
    else
        txtProduct.Text = "Please enter valid number.";
}
```

Comment: You are asking for VB but code is somewhat in C# - not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Also, I think the lines `if (bN && bM && iM > 0 && iM > 0)` don't do what you probably want them to do. (Hint: you can't group-check multiple values like that.)

Comment: I am looking for when i place a number in my textbox 1 and textbox 2 and once i hit my button it will produce the output of {(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)....}

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ, all things are possible:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var tuples = from m in Enumerable.Range(1, int.Parse(txtM.Text))
                         from n in Enumerable.Range(1, int.Parse(txtN.Text))
                         select Tuple.Create(m, n);
            txtProduct.Text = "{" + String.Join(",", tuples) + "}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but im using visual studio and it has to be in C#

Comment: This is C#. LINQ was added to C# years ago. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx