# C# How to permutate all elements with each others in a List of string

Tags: c#, loops, permutation, c#-11.0

I have a string list and i want all permutations of all elements with each others

Example :

```
var myList = new List<string>{ "AB", "CD", "EF", "GK" };
```

and as result i want a string like this.

```
var resultStr = "ABCD,ABEF,ABGK,CDAB,CDEF,CDGK,EFAB,EFCD,EFGK,GKAB,GKCD,GKEF";
```

note that resultStr doesnt include "ABAB","CDCD","EFEF","GKGK"

is there any short way to do this except double for/foreach loops?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Do note that the number of results for `n` input strings is `n factorial`. Which means 13 input strings would result in over 6 billion results, which is already more than the maximum array size of ~2.1 billions that .NET can handle. You probably will want to limit the input length accordingly.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336540/how-to-use-linq-to-find-all-combinations-of-n-items-from-a-set-of-numbers) help?

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool It's only O(n^2), or more precisely N*(N-1).  I think the factorial case would be if you could pair up to N inputs not just 2 of them.

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool actually i was plannig to do this with a string list which has almost 50 elements :( I was asking that can i do this without computing n factorial?

Comment: How about `myList.SelectMany(a => myList.Where(b => b != a).Select(b => a + b)).ToList()`? or the LINQ syntax version, `(from a in myList from b in myList where a != b select a+b).ToList()`?

Comment: @PeterSmith acutally no sir. This is giving me `IEnumarable<IEnumabarable<string>>` and i was looking for a `resultStr`. Probably converting to a string means extra cost i guess

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool OP is asking for Cartesian Product. Why do you think what they wrote relates what they are looking for (and hence your somewhat overestimated n! complexity of desired answer)?

Comment: Right, I was basing it off the description and mention of "permutating all elements with each other", without checking that the example is actually describing a different operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** is there any short way to do this except double for/foreach loops?

Yes, you can use LINQ.

Here's the LINQ syntax expression for your result:

```
var myList = new List<string>{ "AB", "CD", "EF", "GK" };
var result = from a in myList from b in myList where a != b select a+b;
var resultStr = string.Join(",", result);
Console.WriteLine(resultStr);
```

You can also use the LINQ extension methods:

```
var myList = new List<string>{ "AB", "CD", "EF", "GK" };
var result = myList.SelectMany(a => myList.Where(b => b != a).Select(b => a + b));
var resultStr = string.Join(",", result);
Console.WriteLine(resultStr);
```

Both will output

```
ABCD,ABEF,ABGK,CDAB,CDEF,CDGK,EFAB,EFCD,EFGK,GKAB,GKCD,GKEF
```

[.NET Fiddle so you can try it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nVST0e)

Comment: It may be good idea to mention that OP is looking for variation of [Cartesian Product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401961/cartesian-product) and not "permutations" despite what is written in the question/title.

Comment: By using linq lambdas as in example#2 you have an option to use indexes for comparison: var result = myList.SelectMany((a,i) => myList.Where((b,j) => i != j).Select(b => a + b));